# Invalid credentials error for Bing Maps in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, bing-maps, credentials, api-key

I tried to add an aerial map to my web application. This is my Contacts.cshtml:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <h1>Location</h1>
    <hr class="border border-white border-3"/>
    <div id="myMap" style="width:63%;height:500px;"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[my API key]'
            async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function GetMap() {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
                credentials: 'my API key',
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.50632, -0.12714),
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
                zoom: 10
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

I have registered to https://www.bingmapsportal.com and created 2 differend API keys:[API keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXUjC.png)

I tried with both of them but when the map visualizes it shows me the following error message:
[The specified credentials are invalid. You can sign up for a free developer account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJtun.jpg)

I don't understand what the problem is. I found several topics with the same problem but I couldn't find any suggested solutions that work for me. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your credentials in the URL for the map SDK, you don't need to specify them a second time when creating the map. Try removing that second instance.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried it. I switched to OpenStreetMap, which is way easier and better.